# string appending in C for random bytes

Tags: c, string

I have following C code for handling strings

```
#define SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE 33 /* [0..31] bytes random alpha numeric values + 32 byte for null character. */
#define TIME_STAMP_SIZE 32

/* build secret value */
    char secretString[256] = {0};
    char hpci_ws_secret_val[SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE] = {0};
    char sessionId[SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE] = {0};
    char secretSessionId[SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE] = {0};
    char timeStamp[TIME_STAMP_SIZE] = {0};
    int lenTimeStamp = strlen(recvtimestamp);
    int lenWSSecret;
    
    strcpy(hpci_ws_secret_val, hpciWebServerGetSecretVal());
    strncpy(timeStamp, recvtimestamp, lenTimeStamp);
    lenWSSecret = strlen(hpci_ws_secret_val);
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken web secret value %s length %d \n ", hpci_ws_secret_val, lenWSSecret );
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken time stamp %s length: %d \n ", timeStamp, lenTimeStamp);
    
    /* site secret value + timestamp */
    strncpy(secretString, hpci_ws_secret_val, SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE);
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken secretValue %s \n", secretString);
    
    strncat(secretString, timeStamp, lenTimeStamp);
    printf("VRK Valandtime %s \n", secretString);
        
    GetSessionIds(reqId, sessionId, secretSessionId);
    /* session id + secret session id */
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken sessionId %s \n ", sessionId);
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken secretSessionId %s \n ", secretSessionId);
    strncat(secretString, sessionId, SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE );
    strncat(secretString, secretSessionId, SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE);
    
    unsigned char formDigestVal[SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE] = {0};
    unsigned int mdlen = 0;
    printf("VRK ValidateActionToken calculating MD5 for string %s \n ", secretString);
    GetDigestValue("MD5", secretString, strlen(secretString), formDigestVal, &mdlen);
    char strDigestVal[SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE] = {0};
    ConvertRandomValToString(formDigestVal, strDigestVal, SECRET_TOKEN_SIZE );
```

Output:

```
VRK ValidateActionToken web secret value 75E87C8CE72767A63C47918AADED06CB length 32
 length: 11 eActionToken time stamp 1669294822
 VRK ValidateActionToken secretValue 75E87C8CE72767A63C47918AADED06CB
 RK Valandtime 75E87C8CE72767A63C47918AADED06CB1669294822 ------------> secret and time stamp are appeneded correctly
VRK ValidateActionToken sessionId 92030F994ED20A91856E044C40B55F75
 VRK ValidateActionToken secretSessionId 21ED81483883182FADE03128A478EEB0
 VRK ValidateActionToken calculating MD5 for string 75E87C8CE72767A63C47918AADED92030F994ED20A91856E044C40B55F7521ED81483883182FADE03128A478EEB0 ---->Notice here last 4 bytes and time stamp are lost
```

**Question:** I am always observing last 4 bytes of secret value i.e., in this example "06CB" and time stamp is not shown in final string, but session id
and secret session is appending corretly. I tried to check memory corruption but to my knowledge corruption is not observed. Any mistake I am making?

By the way I have added printf statement after GetSessionIds, here printf is shown correctly as expected with timestamp. Another observation is that if I removed timestamp, string is appeneded correctly.
Thanks for your guidence and time.

```
75E87C8CE72767A63C47918AADED##last 4 bytes of secret value and time stamp is lost ###92030F994ED20A91856E044C40B55F7521ED81483883182FADE03128A478EEB0
```

Comment: please add `printf("VRK Valandtime %s \n", secretString);` after `GetSessionIds(reqId, sessionId, secretSessionId);` . Does it print the correct result or are the last chars missing?

Comment: @user253751 I have printed printf("VRK Valandtime %s \n", secretString); after GetSessionIds(reqId, sessionId, secretSessionId); value is printed correctly.

Comment: is it possible to shorten the code to narrow down where the problem is? for example, if you delete all the external calls and use hardcoded values?

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for your inputs. I found that when I hardcoded timestamp it is working fine. Not sure  why time stamp argument is failing. I will debug further.